# Why should I avoid having public setters on domain entity properties

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to apply [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) in one of the applications I am working on now and I cannot say I have grasped it 100% yet.

In most of the samples I am looking at, it seems to be the case that we are trying to avoid having public setters on domain entity properties. For example, I see domain entities implemented like below:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateName(string newName)
    {
        if (newName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("newName");
        }

        Name = newName;
        DomainEvents.Raise(new ProductNameUpdatedEvent(this));
    }
}
```

The usage would look something like:

```
// have a Product object instance here somehow
product.UpdateName("foobar");
```

However, I can achieve the same behavior by implementing the update logic on `Name` property's setter as below:

```
public class Product
{
    private string _name;

    public Product(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            }

            _name = value;
            DomainEvents.Raise(new ProductNameUpdatedEvent(this));
        }
    }
}
```

The usage would look something like below in this case:

```
// have a Product object instance here somehow
product.Name = "foobar";
```

I can see that the first one actually expresses the intent better but I cannot see that much difference here. Other than the better expressiveness, is there any other reason why you want to favor the first option? In DDD, is it a big no-no to go with the second option?

Comment: Maybe look at http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/31/strengthening-your-domain-avoiding-setters/ or https://github.com/julielerman/EF_and_Private_CTORs_n_Setters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DDD is all about the ubiquitous language. CRUD(Create/Read/Update/Delete) terms usually do not find their way in the ubiquitous language. Would you say that a product name can be **updated** or a product can be **renamed** from a business's perspective?

I can't tell for sure since I do not know your domain, but chances are that **rename** is more appropriate.

Now, let's say you see this line of code `product.name = 'some name'`, how would you what that really means? You have to rely on the knowledge that a `Product` cannot be constructed without a name to know for sure that we are actually renaming it. Otherwise, it could also mean that we are naming a product that wasn't initially named.

With `product.rename(...)`, it clearly shows the intention and there's no place for interpretation. It's also much more aligned with the ubiquitous language which is what really matters.

Also, perhaps the business want to capture why the name of a product has been changed? Was it changed because there was a typo? Was it changed for marketing reasons? How would you capture this with a simple setter?

I do not know C# really well so this might not be idiomatic, but here's what seems to make more sense:

```
public class Product {

    //Note: Using ProductName rather than string would be helpful
    //to protect further invariants (e.g. name cannot be empty string)
    private string _name;

    public Product(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name {
        get {
            return _name;
        }

        private set {
            if (value == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("A product must be named");
            }

            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public void rename(string newName) {
        string oldName = Name;

        Name = newName;

        //Assume the entity has the supporting code for a  unique identifier
        //productId
        DomainEvents.Raise(new ProductRenamed(productId, oldName, newName));
    }
}
```

Also note that I enhanced the domain event with additional relevant information. Now something else that is important when handling events is to write them to disk within the same transaction in which the aggregate get's modified. Once the transaction commits, they can be published through a messaging infrastructure for further processing. You want to avoid side-effects from occurring before the transaction actually committed in general.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using domain events it makes your question a bit more interesting.

I came across the following post at some point: http://www.jayway.com/2013/06/20/dont-publish-domain-events-return-them/

So the idea here is to not publish domain events using some arbitrary globally accessible piece of infrastructure but to rather simply return the event as a result of the operation.

I find this option interesting for a couple of reasons:

- No reliance on some `DomainEvents` static implementation that all clients need to use.
- Easier testing since we do not need to hook up to a static singleton `DomainEvents`.

Using your example, though, adds another dimension in that it is not possible to even use a setter in this case since it cannot return the domain event result.  So when using domain events it is going to possible change one's design for the better, I hope :)

Comment: Another alternative to static DomainEvents http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/03/alternatives-to-udis-domain-events.html

Comment: Jef, the ES mechanism you are using is the run-of-the-mill approach that I have come across :) --- it definitely works!  I have, however, never liked putting that infrastructure into the domain as it always felt wrong.  I know you mention that you feel it needs to be close to the domain but I don't quite agree on that since it doesn't appear to be domain related at all ;)  It is in no way part of the UL.  Don't know if you saw my related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719019/who-is-responsible-for-entitys-mutation-when-domain-event-is-raised-ddd/28736530#28736530

Comment: Good point @EbenRoux on doman events. I am actually not using DomainEvents.Raise in my code but I just put it there to see what people will react :) I am not happy having a static class to raise events. It has many problems. I am trying to get the events recorded inside the aggregate as JefClaes pointed and apply visitor pattern to collect the events.